# A table was not found

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6

See this issues below , I having this issue.After creating a Model Like `Burgers PHP` 
My Front Welcome page is working properly but when I go threw `127.0.0.1:8000/burgers`

this address it's error below .

[image]

[image]

here is the error message :

````
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'backyardburger.burgers' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `burgers`) ```
````

Comment: Well, did you create the migration and run `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: @aynber yeah I had migrated .

Comment: can you please paste the model code.

Comment: it''s saying that nothing to migrate !

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Burgers extends Model
{
    //
}

Comment: Can you show your current database with tables?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message. Edit your question to contain all relevant information

Comment: Your table is named `backyardburger`, not `burger`

Comment: but the error is just like ' Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'backyardburger.burgers' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `burgers`) '

Comment: Thank you so much :) <3 love you guys you guys are amazing seriously ;) It is working now . Answer would be : Your table is named backyardburger, not burger : WOW :)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your table to burgers
OR
add the following to your Burger.php

```
 protected $table = 'backyardburger';
```